# Graphql Unknown argument on field

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am new to GraphQL. Whenever I try to send args on (posts) child node like the query below, I  get an error msg "Unknown argument id on field posts of type user". I want to bring a particular post only, not all of them.

```
{ people(id:[1,2]) {
            id
            username
            posts(id:2) {
              title
              tags {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Here is my Schema.js file ..

```
var graphql = require('graphql');
var Db = require('./db');
var users  = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name : 'user',
  description : 'this is user info',
  fields : function(){
    return {
      id :{
        type : graphql.GraphQLInt,
        resolve(user){
          return user.id;
        }
      },
      username :{
        type : graphql.GraphQLString,
        resolve(user){
          return user.username;
        }
      },

      posts:{
        id:{
          type : graphql.GraphQLString,
          resolve(post){
            return post.id;
          }
        },
        type: new  graphql.GraphQLList(posts),
        resolve(user){
          return user.getPosts();
        }
      }


    }
  }
});



var posts  = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name : 'Posts',
  description : 'this is post info',
  fields : function(){
    return {
      id :{
        type : graphql.GraphQLInt,
        resolve(post){
          return post.id;
        }
      },
      title :{
        type : graphql.GraphQLString,
        resolve(post){
          return post.title;
        }
      },
      content:{
        type : graphql.GraphQLString,
        resolve(post){
          return post.content;
        }
      },
      person :{
        type: users,
        resolve(post){
          return post.getUser();
        }
      },

      tags :{
        type: new  graphql.GraphQLList(tags),
        resolve(post){
          return post.getTags();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

var tags  = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name : 'Tags',
  description : 'this is Tags info',
  fields : function(){
    return {
      id :{
        type : graphql.GraphQLInt,
        resolve(tag){
          return tag.id;
        }
      },
      name:{
        type : graphql.GraphQLString,
        resolve(tag){
          return tag.name;
        }
      },
      posts :{
        type: new  graphql.GraphQLList(posts),
        resolve(tag){
          return tag.getPosts();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

var query = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name : 'query',
  description : 'Root query',
  fields : function(){
    return {
     people :{
        type : new  graphql.GraphQLList(users),
        args :{
          id:{type: new graphql.GraphQLList(graphql.GraphQLInt)},
          username:{
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
          }
        },
        resolve(root,args){
          return Db.models.user.findAll({where:args});
        }
      },

      posts:{
        type : new  graphql.GraphQLList(posts),
        args :{
          id:{
            type: graphql.GraphQLInt
          },
          title:{
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
          },
        },
        resolve(root,args){
          return Db.models.post.findAll({where:args});
        }
      },

      tags :{
        type : new  graphql.GraphQLList(tags),
        args :{
          id:{
            type: graphql.GraphQLInt
          },
          name:{
            type: graphql.GraphQLString
          },
        },
        resolve(root,args){
          return Db.models.tag.findAll({where:args});
        }
      }

    }
  }

});
var Schama = new graphql.GraphQLSchema({
  query : query,
  mutation : Mutation
})

module.exports = Schama;
```

Comment: What does your schema look like? Most likely you didn't declare the id argument correctly in the schema.

Comment: I have added my schema.js file please check once @helfer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

looks like you are missing args on users, hence, it should look like this:

```
var users  = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name : 'user',
  description : 'this is user info',
  fields : function(){
    return {
      id :{
        type : graphql.GraphQLInt,
        resolve(user){
          return user.id;
        }
      },
      username :{
        type : graphql.GraphQLString,
        resolve(user){
          return user.username;
        }
      },

      posts:{
        args: {
        id:{
            type : graphql.GraphQLInt,
        },
        type: new  graphql.GraphQLList(posts),
        resolve(user, args){
          // Code here to use args.id
          return user.getPosts();
        }
      }


    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Because of your tip I no longer have my issues with red swirlies on nested types, thank you! 

However, in my example, I had to put the args-tag on my INPUT definition and not the OUTPUT definition as you are giving an example of above... Maybe Achyat does not need to use both...?

Also, you are missing a curly bracket before type, as I believe args should not contain type and resolver... I just wanted to point out this for those that might be in a similar situation...

Answer (score 0):

You this error if the argument does not exist in the field.

For example, in this case, invalidArg does not exist in the list. The only possible arguments are last, after, first, before, orderBy and ownedByViewer. If you try to pass anything else, you will get an error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `posts` (plural) with `post` (singular).

```
post(id:2) {
          title
          tags {
            name
          }
        }
```