# GraphQL query some record error "Unknown argument ..."

Tags: graphql

Currently i'm following this great tutorial on http://codevampires.com/2017/11/16/a-crud-app-with-apollo-graphql-nodejs-express-mongodb-angular-v5/. It's CRUD working perfectly on my localhost also.

Here is my query

> {
>    users (name : "eee") {
>      id
>      name
>    }
>   }

My problem is when I try to query just 1 record, it's give me error

> "message": "Unknown argument \"name\" on field \"users\" of type \"Query\"."

here is grqphql ide :

> https://graphql-crud-server.herokuapp.com/graphql

please help,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graphql Unknown argument on field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691111/graphql-unknown-argument-on-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you post your schema as well?

Generally you would have something like this.

```
type Query {
    users: [User]
    user(name: String): User
}
```

The user(name: String): User part is basically saying you have a query that returns one user based on a name variable that will be type of String.

You could also do this on your users query, but the query would still have to accept a variable. And then if it returns only one user, that user object would be in an array.

```
users(name: String): [User]
```

Your resolver should look something like this.

```
Query: {
    users: function(root, args, context, info) {
        if (args.name) {
            const user = usersArray.find(user => user.name === args.name)

            return [user] // Schema is expecting an array
        }

        return usersArray
    }
}
```